# C#.Net Network tool to Listen to IP traffic and Sort them with predifined data

Tags: c#, network-programming

I'm developing a network tool and I want to map IPs to Area Names.

Ex:
10.0.0.1   - 10.0.0.100   = area A
10.0.0.101 - 10.0.0.200   = area B etc.

And when a request comes from a certain IP the tool should display the Area Name to the user. I'm doing it on C#.Net

Can anyone give me the outline of the software I should build.. Following is what I have in mind..
1) A module to hold a database to map IPs to Area Names
2) A module to listen to requests comes to that server.
3) A module to sort the IPs and Alert the User.

I welcome any suggestion, guidance, warning or instructions. Thanks in advance.
-Zerone

Answer (score 1):

that is an NMP, im doing one as my collagre grade test... in som days i can send you the custom code, but first try to do a broadcast to all the IP adresses

Comment: Thank you very much and I will try the broadcasting.